# Android WebView InflateException on android 7.0

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, android-webview, inflate-exception

I have WebView on my application and I got many same errors on android 7.0 from users while inflating WebView fragment.

Error log:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView

WebView fragment layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wvAparat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

I got this error from these devices:

> SM-G950F  Android 7.0
>
> SM-J330F  Android 7.0
>
> Moto E (4) Plus Android 7.1.1

Comment: may be cause of error is `android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat` it has nothing to do with webview

Comment: @Tej Maybe, I will test it.

Comment: @VolkanSahin45 No error is clear android view InflateException.

Comment: try with LinearLayout instead of `android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat`

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely device related. here is a link for more information:
https://www.androidpolice.com/2016/07/20/google-explains-chrome-will-become-webview-android-7-0/

My hunch would be, if you find one of these devices, to check if they have Chrome installed. If not, that's your answer. No idea for a workaround.